# Batch file: Open cmd, run VS Command Prompt, execute Makecert

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I need to do this in a batch file:

1. Open cmd
2. Run VS Command Prompt via cmd
3. Execute this command
   "makecert -sv SignRoot.pvk -cy authority -r sha1 -a -n \"CN=Certificate\" -ss my -sr localmachine certificate.cer"

So far, I've done 1 and 2, my problem is getting into #3.

Here's what I have so far.

```
start  cmd.exe /k "%comspec% /c  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have VS 10.0 installed to test this, but try putting these two line in a batch file:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
makecert -sv SignRoot.pvk -cy authority -r sha1 -a -n "CN=Certificate" -ss my -sr localmachine certificate.cer
```

Comment: it didnt work.. :(

Comment: I've figured it out.
Simply put "call" before "C:\.... "

Comment: Good to hear -- I was thinking something like that might be necessary, but you beat me to it. Cheers.